# Symfony4. Конфликт при установке twig/extensions, как исправить?

Tags: twig, symfony4

При попытке установить `composer require twig/extensions`, появляется куча конфликтов:

```bsh
     Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.4
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.3
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.1.0
    - twig/twig v1.27.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.28.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.28.1 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.28.2 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.29.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.30.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.31.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.32.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.33.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.33.1 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v1.33.2 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v2.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v2.1.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v2.2.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v2.3.0 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v2.3.1 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - twig/twig v2.3.2 conflicts with doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.4|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.4|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.4|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.4|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.3|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.3|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.3|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.3|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.2|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.2|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.2|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.2|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.1|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.1|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at 2.1.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.1|remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/extensions v1.5.1|don't install twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Installation request for twig/extensions ^1.5 -> satisfiable by twig/extensions[v1.5.0, v1.5.1, v1.5.2, v1.5.3, v1.5.4].
    - Conclusion: remove twig/twig v3.0.3|install twig/twig v1.27.0|install twig/twig v1.28.0|install twig/twig v1.28.1|install twig/twig v1.28.2|install twig/twig v1.29.0|install twig/twig v1.30.0|install twig/twig v1.31.0|install twig/twig v1.32.0|install twig/twig v1.33.0|install twig/twig v1.33.1|install twig/twig v1.33.2|install twig/twig v2.0.0|install twig/twig v2.1.0|install twig/twig v2.2.0|install twig/twig v2.3.0|install twig/twig v2.3.1|install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - twig/extensions v1.5.0 requires twig/twig ~1.27|~2.0 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.27.0, v1.28.0, v1.28.1, v1.28.2, v1.29.0, v1.30.0, v1.31.0, v1.32.0, v1.33.0, v1.33.1, v1.33.2, v1.34.0, v1.34.1, v1.34.2, v1.34.3, v1.34.4, v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v1.36.0, v1.37.0, v1.37.1, v1.38.0, v1.38.1, v1.38.2, v1.38.3, v1.38.4, v1.39.0, v1.39.1, v1.40.0, v1.40.1, v1.41.0, v1.42.0, v1.42.1, v1.42.2, v1.42.3, v1.42.4, v1.42.5, v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.11.1, v2.11.2, v2.11.3, v2.12.0, v2.12.1, v2.12.2, v2.12.3, v2.12.4, v2.12.5, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.41.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.42.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.42.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.42.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.42.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.42.4, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.42.5, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.10.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.4, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.5, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.4, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.4, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.36.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.37.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.37.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.38.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.38.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.38.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.38.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.38.4, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.39.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.39.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.40.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.40.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.4, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.5, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.6, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.7, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.8, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.5.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.6.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.6.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.6.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.7.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.7.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.7.2, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.7.3, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.7.4, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.8.0, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.8.1, v3.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.9.0, v3.0.3].
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v3.0.3) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v3.0.3].
```

Содержание `composer.json`:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.19",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как установить `twig/extensions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, удалив: `"symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0"`.

После чего установил: `"twig/twig": "^1.27|^2.0"` и установив `"twig/extensions": "^1.5"`